# ¿Cómo copiar y partir un archivo en diferentes arrays de bytes?¿Como unirlos nuevamente para que no se dañe su contenido?

Tags: c#, .net, archivo, encriptación

En el programa lo que intento es que pueda encriptar archivos más pesados pero el método de File.ReadAllBytes solo puede almacenar hasta 2GB, y 2 GB es muy poco para la cantidad de datos que podemos manejar en la actualidad.

Tenia pensado que talvez dividiendo el archivo en partes podría aumentar la capacidad del programa para encriptar.
Ejemplo: Si tengo un archivo de 8 Gb lo divido en 4 arreglos de bytes, los encripto y los imprimo. Igualmente para desencriptar, los divido, los desencripto y los imprimo.

```
  public byte[] EncriptarArchivo(string rutaArchivo, string personalkey)
        {
            byte[] bytesEncriptados = null;
            /*ReadAllBytes tiene un limite de 2 gb:
            en la siguiente linea estoy leyendo los bytes de un archivo, pero si el archivo es muy 
            grande no permitira obtener sus bytes*/
            byte[] bytesAencriptar = File.ReadAllBytes(rutaArchivo);
            byte[] clave = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(personalkey);
            byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            using (var memoStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using(var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(clave, salt, 1000);
                    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize/8);
                    aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    using(CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(),
                        CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(bytesAencriptar, 0, bytesAencriptar.Length);
                        cryptoStream.Close();
                    }
                    bytesEncriptados = memoStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return bytesEncriptados;
        }
```

Comment: Te vas a demorar lo mismo, cifrar el archivo grande te da un tiempo T y los archivos divididos tiempos más pequeño pero son divisiones del archivo original, que cuando sumas los tiempos de estas divisiones va a ser lo mismo que cifrar el archivo original, de hecho con este método te demoraría mas pues tendrías que dividir el fichero, cifrar las divisiones y después unir el fichero, mientras que de la otra forma aunque se demore cifras una vez y ya

Comment: Gracias por responder. Estoy de acuerdo, pero el problema es que este método de File.ReadAllBytes tiene un limite de 2 GB busque otro método y también tenia esa misma limitación, en si me sirve cualquiera forma que cargue un archivo pesado.

Comment: Puede que te sea útil ver [`StreamReader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netcore-3.1) y [`StreamReader.Read(Char[], Int32, Int32)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamReader_Read_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_). Con eso, puedes leer un archivo a porciones (a bloques).
(Si encuentras la solución, te aliento a dar una respuesta a tu propia pregunta. Así poder cerrarla y que pueda ayudar a más personas con el mismo problema)